# In Vim: Searching for text but putting the cursor at the end of the match?

Tags: vim, neovim

Is there a way of searching for a pattern, but placing the cursor at the end of the pattern rather than at the beginning, when there is a match   ?

For example, /my ENTER would place the cursor at the beginning of 'myvariable' ('m').

I find that often, it would be handy if the cursor was placed immediately after the end of the search pattern (here, on the 'v'). Is this possible ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `:help /` you can see the `/{pattern}/{offset}<CR>` pattern.
From `:help offset`:

```
                    *search-offset* *{offset}*
These commands search for the specified pattern.  With "/" and "?" an
additional offset may be given.  There are two types of offsets: line offsets
and character offsets.

The offset gives the cursor position relative to the found match:
    [num]   [num] lines downwards, in column 1
    +[num]  [num] lines downwards, in column 1
    -[num]  [num] lines upwards, in column 1
    e[+num] [num] characters to the right of the end of the match    ## This is the one you want
    e[-num] [num] characters to the left of the end of the match
    s[+num] [num] characters to the right of the start of the match
    s[-num] [num] characters to the left of the start of the match
    b[+num] [num] identical to s[+num] above (mnemonic: begin)
    b[-num] [num] identical to s[-num] above (mnemonic: begin)
    ;{pattern}  perform another search, see |//;|

If a '-' or '+' is given but [num] is omitted, a count of one will be used.
When including an offset with 'e', the search becomes inclusive (the
character the cursor lands on is included in operations).
```

---

So in your case use `/my/e+` (or `/my/e+1`) to land on the `v` of `myvariable`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `/my/e`. This will place the cursor at the end of the pattern. If you use `/my./e` it will place the cursor on the first position after the pattern.